# AdjustWindowRectEx returns different results in VS and C++Builder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, c++builder

I try to use `AdjustWindowRectEx()` function to get the sizes of the window frame with aero theme enabled.
But I found that `AdjustWindowRectEx()` function returns different results in **Visual Studio 2012** and  **C++ Builder XE7**.

All tests performed on Windows 7.

Firstly I try to get the window frame sizes for these styles (it is which corresponds to BorderStyle = **bsDialog** in C++ Builder):

```
DWORD styles = WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_SYSMENU;
DWORD ex_styles = WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
 
RECT r = {0};
AdjustWindowRectEx(&r, styles, false, ex_styles);
```

It returns:

- VS: left: **-8**; top: **-30**; right: **8**; bottom: **8**
- CB: left: -3; top: -25; right: 3; bottom: 3

Here, the code executed in Visual Studio returns the correct result. And on C++Builder - there are wrong return values.

Let's try another styles (it is equivalent to BorderStyle = **bsToolWindow** in C++ Builder):

```
DWORD styles = WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_SYSMENU | WS_OVERLAPPED;
DWORD ex_styles = WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
```

It returns:

- VS: left: **-8**; top: **-26**; right: **8**; bottom: **8**
- CB: left: -3; top: -21; right: 3; bottom: 3

Here, the code executed in Visual Studio returns the correct result also. But in Builder not.

But I found that return values are equal both on Visual Studio and C++ Builder with these styles (it is corresponds to BorderStyle = **bsSizeable** in C++ Builder):

```
DWORD styles = WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
DWORD ex_styles = WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
```

It returns:

- VS: left: **-8**; top: **-30**; right: **8**; bottom: **8**
- CB: left: **-8**; top: **-30**; right: **8**; bottom: **8**

And my question is: why `AdjustWindowRectEx()` function returns different values for the same request styles on Visual Studio and C++ Builder?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that Visual Studio has created a default manifest for your app that means the OS lies to you less about certain things, and Code Builder hasn't.

Comment: Modern C++Builder versions also create a default manifest ([see this](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Customizing_the_Windows_Application_Manifest_File)). But the OP is using an old (2014) version of C++Builder, I don't recall if that version did or not.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I extracted the manifest file from the app compiled in VS (which returned the correct result) and added it to the app compiled in C++Builder. But the application compiled in the builder still returns incorrect values. So it seems that the problem is not with the manifest file.
I also created a console application in C++ Builder and when I run the same code I get wrong result. This is weird.

Answer (score 0):

By experience, I found out that to get correct window frame sizes using  `AdjustWindowRectEx()` function compiled in C++ Builder (and Visual Stuidio also), it is necessary to add the `WS_THICKFRAME` style to request.

Also to adapt the code to different window styles, it is necessary to check whether it is appropriate to add `WS_THICKFRAME`: namely, if the styles `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_THICKFRAME` aren't set (in case when the window has no frames), the `WS_THICKFRAME` style isn't added to request.

```
RECT r = {0};
DWORD styles = GetWindowLongPtr(Handle, GWL_STYLE);
styles |= (!(styles & WS_CAPTION) && !(styles & WS_THICKFRAME)) ? 0 : WS_THICKFRAME;
AdjustWindowRectEx(&r, styles, false, GetWindowLongPtr(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE));
```

Of course, the real reason stays unknown.